# VB Visual Studio Cells erro

Tags: microsoft-excel, vb.net, vba

Antes de mais obrigado pela vossa ajuda.
Sou novato com código e não consegui obter resposta a estas questões mesmo com procura na net.

Estou a tentar desenvolver um código no visual studio em vb.net (console) que abre um ficheiro excel, lê o used range da sheet, e identifica a ultima coluna usada. A ideia é usar esta ultima coluna e fazer um loop pela linha A, todas as células até à ultima coluna e apagar as colunas que não tenham conteúdo/nome.

No entanto o Cells está-me a dar um erro 'Cells is not declared. It may not be accessible due to its level protection'.

```
Module Module1

    Dim excel As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
    Dim wb As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook
    Dim ws As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet
    Sub Main()

        excel = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application

        Dim reportPath As String
        reportPath = "excelFile.xlsx"

        wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(reportPath) 'Open the excel the file'
        excel.Visible = True 'makes it visible

        ws = CType(wb.Sheets("Sheet1"), Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet) 'select a sheet and activates'
        ws.Activate()

        ws.UsedRange.Select() 'select used range
        Dim lastCol As Integer = ws.UsedRange.Columns.Count
        MsgBox(lastCol)
        ws.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, lastCol)).Select()



    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow **in Portuguese**. As the name implies, the official language used here is Portuguese. So, can you please translate your question? If you prefer, you may also ask this same question in [the English StackOverflow site](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: Feito. Achava que estava no ingles. Obrigado

Comment: Podem validar a questão?

Comment: Você fala que há um erro mas não diz qual.

Comment: Obrigado @ramaral . Penso que agora está melhor.

Comment: Não será `ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 1), ws.Cells(1, lastCol)).Select()`?

Comment: É sim. Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

O código correto formatado é:

```
Module Module1

    Dim excel As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
    Dim wb As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook
    Dim ws As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet
    Sub Main()

        excel = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application

        Dim reportPath As String
        reportPath = "excelFile.xlsx"

        wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(reportPath) 'Open the excel the file'
        excel.Visible = True 'makes it visible

        ws = CType(wb.Sheets("Sheet1"), Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet) 'select a sheet and activates'
        ws.Activate()

        ws.UsedRange.Select() 'select used range
        Dim lastCol As Integer = ws.UsedRange.Columns.Count
        MsgBox(lastCol)
        ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 1), ws.Cells(1, lastCol)).Select()



    End Sub

End Module
```